# Cloud labels affecting % testing accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pca, feature-engineering

I have 96 features and the labels are represented by 1 and -1 for inputting to a deep learning model.

### 1- PCA

Here the 3 axis represent the 3 first principal components. The blue cloud represents the labels 1 and the red cloud represents the labels -1.

[image]

Even if we can identify two different clouds visually, they are stick together. I think we can face a problem during the training phase because of that.

### 2- t-SNE

For the same features and labels with t-SNE, we can still distinguish two clouds, but again they are stick together.

[image]
[image]

## Questions :

1- Does the fact that the two clouds of dots are stick together can affect the % accuracy during the training and testing phase?

2- When we remove the red and blue color, we have somehow only one big cloud. Is there a way to work around the problem the two clouds ''stuck'' together?

Answer (score 1):

What you call sticking together, means that in this space, your data isn't linearly separable. It doesn't seem to be nonlinearly separable either. I would expect with this these components, that you get poor accuracy for sure.

The way to work around the problem is more or different data. You have some options.

1) What about including more principal components? Maybe, 4, 5, 10 components would solve your problem. That might not work depending on your dataset, but it's the most obvious thing to try first.

2) You could try alternative matrix decomposition techniques. PCA isn't the only one. There's NMF, kernel PCA, LSA, and many others. Which one works best for you will fundamentally be determined by the distribution of your data.

3) Use any other type of feature selection. Frankly, 96 isn't that many, to begin with. You intend on doing deep learning? Wouldn't you normally put all 96 features into a deep learning model? There any many other ways to do feature selection besides matrix decomposition if you need to.

Good luck.

Comment: How can I use 4, 5 or 10 principal components and still having a visual?

Comment: You are getting ahead of yourself. You need a good model before you can worry about the visual. There are more advanced visualization techniques. But even with just the basics, maybe you visualize the 2nd, 4th, and 5th component? Maybe that combination looks nice. Just because you can only see 3 components simply, doesn't mean they have to be the first three components.